# matrix theory with 2-norm

Tags: matrices

let $\gamma=sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\|H(x)^T(A^2+B(x)B(x)^T)^{-1}H(x)\|$,where $A$ is a negative definite matrix，$A^2+B(x)B(x)^T$ is a positive definite matrix,the norm is Euclidean norm.I want to show
$H(x)^T(A^2+B(x)B(x)^T)H(x)-\gamma^{-2}I ,\forall x \in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a positive semidefinite matrix，Here, you can add any reasonable condition to $H(x)$. Of course, it would be best if you could provide a necessary condition for $H(x)$, but I think that might be quite difficult. I've been stuck on this problem for a long time and hope to get everyone's help."

Comment: It will be if $\gamma^{-2}$ is less than the smallest eigenvalue of $H(x)^T(A^2 + B(x)B(x)^T)^{-1}H(x)$ for every $x$.

Comment: Of course, such conditions are acceptable, but I would prefer to set conditions directly on $H(x)$ alone, as this problem has some practical background. Imposing conditions in that manner would defeat the purpose.